# Correct and efficient programming style

Tags: java, exception, coding-style, refactoring

There is a class X.
A method `method()` in X class throws `SomeException`.

I wonder which method of handling exceptions is better - more efficient. If it is surrounding try-block method throwing exceptions and all dependencies or keeping dependences outside try-block, but returning from method after failure.

1.

```
public void test() {
     X x = new X();

     try {
          T temp = tx.method();
          temp.doWhatever();
     }

     catch(SomeException e) { handleException(e); }
}
```

**or**

2.

```
public void test() {
     X x = new X();
     T temp = null;
     try {
          temp = tx.method();
     }

     catch(SomeException e) { 
          handleException(e);
          return;
     }

     temp.doWhatever();
}
```

---

**Edited: (after your annotations)**

What is more I undersand my code like that:

1.
`tx.method()` will throw an exception so the next thing which will be excetuted is `catch`- block. It doesn't matted that `temp` is still `null` because program skips `temp.doWhatever();` line and there will be no `NullPointerException`.

2.
Here I use `return` instruction because I don't want to execute `temp.doWhatever()` because `temp` is `null`

Comment: Option 1 looks much clearer to me

Comment: (1) Why is one `public void test` and the other is `public static void main`? (2) You do realize that in the second block of code, it means `temp.doWhatever` will not have its exceptions caught?

Comment: @notfed: For your question (2), OP didn't say anything about `doWhatever` throws `Exception`, though (and we can assume nothing is thrown).

Comment: It depends on context, what you want to communicate, the rest of the method, etc. Neither is more efficient.

Comment: number 1 is the best way to do it; it's the way that I handle exceptions.  Bear in mind that you really only want to catch your exception if you're going to do something to handle it.  otherwise you might as well let your exception bubble up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second case won't even compile (and it does not even make sense), as `temp` is not visible outside the `try` block. In any case, I would go for this:

```
public void test() {
     X x = new X();

     try {
          T temp = tx.method();
          temp.doWhatever();
     }

     catch(SomeException e) { handleException(e); }
}
```

Since if initializing `temp` fails, the rest of the `temp` operations should not execute.

Comment: "Since if initializing temp fails, the rest of the temp operations should not execute."

I agree with you so that's why I placed return in second example.

Comment: @squixy: Now your two snippets are equivalent. I would still choose the first one because it's not recommended to have `return` statements scattered across the method, since it's a bit more difficult to understand how the code will behave.

Answer (score 1):

Only the first is possible, as temp is declared inside.

I personally opt for the first, as otherwise one needs to declare before the try: T temp = null.

---

***After correction of question:***

**Pro first**

The first code has less jump instructions and the variable `temp` is more local, and is without null initialisation.

Also the coding style is more compact, without null initialisation, a possible error point.

Furthermore exceptions should be kept out of view; it easier to read the first version.
Exceptions should not interrupt the linear coding and reading processes.

**Pro second**

It is more clear where the exception can stem from.

Answer (score 1):

One of the key points of the way exceptions work is that you can use your style number 1: let a block of code execute with the peace of mind that wherever it breaks, the flow will be interrupted and the error handled. So I would always advise the first style.

Answer (score 0):

It is not good to have more than one return in a method. But thats just to have understandable code. You can avoid returns with booleans and ifs.

I think there is no efficience problem. if a exception occurs at the first statement then the second is not executed. If there is no exception then ... hm... i think there should be no overhead because of the second method. You could inform you how the "assembler" code looks like with try catch :D

In my opinion it is more important to write undestandable code. The compilers nowadays are very good and optimize the most things very good.

Answer (score 0):

Option two is bad for extensibility reasons. Suppose later someone decided that test() should be doing something after test.doWhatever(), even if the exceptional case is encountered. They would have to refactor the code to option one at that point. Since there is no cost to using option one from the start, there is no reason they should have to do that.

Further, the design principle of the try/catch block is violated by returning from the catch block, even though the compiler will still accept it. For the catch to be a return point, it should be throwing an exception, since the action is invoked because of an exceptional case.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see any difference with the two methods.

Comment: There is no difference to what they do... But this is a _coding style_ question. That's the point.